# Html scaling row

Tags: html, html-table

I have a table with this layout[image]

As you can see the first row on a left is scaling accordingly to "Notes" column. How can I make left rows to be all the same height? Like this: [image]

Here is fiddle for you with my layout.
http://jsfiddle.net/CleverKetchup/nhe26e8y/

And the code:

```
<table cellspacing="1" cellpadding="5" width="100%" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">ARRIVAL<br/>ATIS 1</td>
        <td rowspan="2"></td>
        <td colspan="5">NOTES</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td colspan="5" rowspan="3">SELECTED PROFILES:</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>ARRIVAL<br/>ATIS 2</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>ALT<br/>ATIS</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution 1: css overflow

Why don't you use css `td{ overflow:auto; }` in the notes content `<td>` ?

### Solution 2: embedded table

Why don't you use a table inside another table? This way, you could easily have independent control of row width / height with css?

i.e.:

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
        <td class="td1">
            <!-- TABLE 1 -->
            <table cellpadding="5" class="table1" height="300px" border="1" width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td class="tdata">
                        ARRIVAL<br />
                        ATIS 1
                    </td>
                    <td class="tdata">
                        data of ATIS 1
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="tdata">
                        ARRIVAL<br />
                        ATIS 2
                    </td>
                    <td class="tdata">
                        data of ATIS 2
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="tdata">
                        ALT<br />
                        ATIS
                    </td>
                    <td class="tdata">
                        data of ATIS
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td class="td2">
            <!-- TABLE 2 -->
            <table cellpadding="5" border="1" class="table2" height="300px" width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td class="tnotes" height="32px" width="100%">
                        NOTES
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="5">SELECTED PROFILES:
                        SELECTED PROFILES:

                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```